# How to configure VS to use TFS for one solution, and TourtiseSVN on another

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visual-studio-2012, tfs, tortoisesvn

I have two clients.  One wants me to use TFS, the other wants me to use TortoiseSVN.

They are completely different solutions.  Is it possible to configure VS to use them both, ie one for one project, and one for the other?

I have just been using TFS so far with VS.

Comment: It seems that to do this, you need to manually change the Source Control Plug-In setting each time you switch from one project to the other.

Comment: OK, thanks for confirming this.